# How to capture a backspace on the onkeydown event

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

I have a function that is triggered by the [`onkeydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) event of a textbox. How can I tell if the user has hit either the backspace key or the del key?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", KeyCheck);  //or however you are calling your method
function KeyCheck(event)
{
   var KeyID = event.keyCode;
   switch(KeyID)
   {
      case 8:
      alert("backspace");
      break; 
      case 46:
      alert("delete");
      break;
      default:
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: i am unable to do so on  type =tel or type=password

Comment: There's a lot "yuckie" about the code in this answer: identifiers that do not follow common javascript naming conventions, creating a variable that would better have been inlined (IMO), unindented case statements. Nonetheless, it does answer the question...

Comment: Note: event.keyCode is deprecated; consider event.key instead. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 34):

## event.key === "Backspace" or "Delete"

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. No more arbitrary number codes!

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
    if (key === "Backspace" || key === "Delete") {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: Good info, but you should `event.preventDefault();` instead of `return false` as your example is not an inline one...

Answer (score 27):

As long as you're okay not supporting ancient browsers, use the [`.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) or [`.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) attributes of the [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). These [are supported in over 97% of users' browsers](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-key) as of July 2023. Code to use them should look something like this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.code == 'Delete') {
        console.log('The physical key pressed was the DELETE key');
    }
    if (event.code == 'Backspace') {
        console.log('The physical key pressed was the BACKSPACE key');
    } 
    if (event.key == 'Delete') {
        console.log('The keypress meant the same as pressing DELETE');
        // This can happen for one of two reasons:
        // 1. The user pressed the DELETE key
        // 2. The user pressed FN+BACKSPACE on a small Mac keyboard where
        //    FN+BACKSPACE deletes the character in front of the text cursor,
        //    instead of the one behind it.
    }
    if (event.key == 'Backspace') {
        console.log('The keypress meant the same as pressing BACKSPACE');
    }
});
```

If for some reason you need to support ancient browsers, code to do this should instead use the deprecated [`.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) attribute (though see discussion below of why this older interface is inferior):

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 8) {
        console.log('BACKSPACE was pressed');
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 46) {
        console.log('DELETE was pressed');
    }
});
```

One benefit of the change from the legacy `.keyCode` to the newer `.key` and `.code` is having more powerful and programmer-friendly handling of non-ASCII keys - see [the specification that lists all the possible key values](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events-key/), which are human-readable strings like `"Backspace"` and `"Delete"` and include values for everything from modifier keys specific to Japanese keyboards to obscure media keys. Another benefit is that the new interface distinguishes between *the meaning of a modified keypress* and *the physical key that was pressed*.

This is, it turns out, highly relevant to this question! On [small Mac keyboards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0z9A.jpg), there is no <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, only a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. However, pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is equivalent to pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> on a normal keyboard - that is, it deletes the character *after* the text cursor instead of the one before it. Depending upon your use case, in code you might want to handle a press of <kbd>Backspace</kbd> with <kbd>Fn</kbd> held down as either Backspace or Delete. That's why the new interface lets you choose which to check for.

The `.key` attribute gives you the *meaning* of the keypress, so <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will yield the string `"Delete"`. The `.code` attribute gives you the physical key, so <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will still yield the string `"Backspace"`.

Answer (score 8):

In your function check for the keycode 8 (backspace) or 46 (delete)

[Keycode information](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)
[Keycode list](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it works outside of firefox:

```
callback (event){
  if (event.keyCode === event.DOM_VK_BACK_SPACE || event.keyCode === event.DOM_VK_DELETE)
    // do something
  }
}
```

if not, replace `event.DOM_VK_BACK_SPACE` with `8` and `event.DOM_VK_DELETE` with `46` or define them as constant (for better readability)