# Are there limits and/or prohibited characters for form field names?

Tags: php, html, forms

As the title says, **are there limits and/or prohibited characters** for form **field names**?

- If I use an `sha512()` hash for field name, are there drawbacks to this (it's pretty lengthy)?
- Or, are there any drawbacks when using `-:x:&copy;:y:` as field name?
- Or, may I use a serialized array for field name?
- Or, what if the field contains a space character?
- What about "/downloads/ready/games/" as a key?

I bet, this isn't HTML specific, but more PHP (scripting language) specific, whether after the posting, the values can be read. Theoretically, it may also apply to array keys in general.

One more thing I thought about, the usage of "readable" form fields has become so popular/mainstream because forms are mostly used for storing data inside a database, where field name resembles the column within database. Correct me if I'm wrong.

So, yes, am I free to use whatever I want in these forms, or I may end up with errors/unreadable data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-form-name) defines the allowed values for `name` attributes on `<form>` elements.

> The value must not be the empty string, and the value must be unique amongst the `form` elements in the `forms` collection that it is in, if any.

---

Of course it also defines [allowed values for the `name` attribute on form controls](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-fe-name) (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, &c.) (emphasis added).

> *4.10.19.1 Naming form controls*
>
> The `name` content attribute gives the name of the form control, as
>   used in form submission and in the `form` element's `elements` object.
>   If the attribute is specified, its value must not be the empty string.
>
> **Any non-empty value for `name` is allowed, but the names "`_charset_`" and "`isindex`" are special:**
>
> *`isindex`*
>   This value, if used as the name of a Text control that is the first control in a form that is submitted using the
>   `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mechanism, causes the submission
>   to only include the value of this control, with no name.
>
> *`_charset_`*
>   This value, if used as the name of a Hidden control with no `value` attribute, is automatically given a value during
>   submission consisting of the submission character encoding.

Comment: But that's specific to `form` name, not it's fields. So, that means, in HTML5 I am free to go with my custom names?

Comment: My apologies - I missed the (yes, you bolded it in the question) **field** part. That does make more sense now. See my edit.

Comment: But I suppose that applies only to HTML5, and HTML4 is still left behind with what @KristerAndersson has posted?

Answer (score 2):

> `ID` and `NAME` tokens must begin with a letter `([A-Za-z])` and may
>   be followed by any number of letters, digits `([0-9])`, hyphens
>   `("-")`, underscores `("_")`, colons `(":")`, and periods `(".")`.

[Read this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata)

Comment: What do you mean is there a higher version?

Comment: WOW, you are kidding, this seems interesting.

Comment: You answered an HTML5 question just a few hours ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element/8355050#8355050

Comment: HTML5 isn't even standardized yet.

Comment: @Herbert I think you mean "finalized." There are definitely _standards_. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

Comment: That's for validation purposes, I suppose. But, does it apply to server-side scripting?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: You're right. I meant "finalized". My point is: in my book, HTML 4 isn't outdated until HTML5 is _finalized_. :)

Comment: @MattBall - I was kidding. The question was marked `html` and not `html5`.