# How can I prevent letters inside a text element?

Tags: html, safari, textinput

I like to have an input with maximum length 3.

These input value should be only numbers no letters.

By referring to this post: [why is <input type="number" maxlength="3"> not working in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361193/why-is-input-type-number-maxlength-3-not-working-in-safari) you can see that I **can't use** `<input type="numbers">`

So how can I prevent letters inside an text-input-element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery.

```
$("#myField").keyup(function() {
    $("#myField").val(this.value.match(/[0-9]*/));
});
```

Comment: You need to consider chrome browser in android tablet where key events doesn't help much.

Comment: Don't forget to account for negative numbers and decimals if needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script>
function checkPattern(elem) {
  if(!elem.value.match('^' + elem.getAttribute('pattern') + '$')) {
    alert('The value must be 3 digits.');
  }
}   
</script>
<input maxlength=3 pattern=[0-9]{3} onchange=
   checkPattern(this)>
```

Modify the error handling according to the application. The idea is to use an HTML5 `pattern` attribute and back it up with simple JavaScript code, for browsers that do not support the attribute but have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: like your vanillajs solution, but hate your unquoted attributes. Nonetheless nice use of new attribute and shim for IE (and some other unnotable browsers;) ).