# Trying to only allow 4 numbers in a field

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make sure only to validate 4 digits which can only be numbers in a field, and letters cannot be accepted. Its for this field.

```
<tr>
<td id="Exam_Number">Exam Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Exam_Number" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Like @tom said, what have you tried so far? Have you done research to find your answer before posting? There is more then enough documentation about validation on the web.

Comment: i've tried loads, like changing the type to number and setting a min and max, and some stuff i found on here and yes snaple, i googled it and looked on here. However the ones i found that didnt work for me i could powerpoint as evidence towards my project.

Comment: Is this about client-side validation, or server-side validation (which technology?), or both? There are old questions on both topics, probably with good answers.

Comment: Ive worked it out now and will edit my code to the answer incase anyone else shall want to know.

Answer (score 2):

Helpful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361193/why-is-input-type-number-maxlength-3-not-working-in-safari)

Specifically, you'd want to change your input element to:

`<input type="text" maxlength="4" pattern="[0-9]{4}" title="Four digit test number" name="Exam_Number"/>`

AND use jQuery to only allow digits as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363661/how-can-i-prevent-letters-inside-a-text-element)

```
$("#myField").keyup(function() {
    $("#myField").val(this.value.match(/[0-9]*/));
});
```

Comment: Also, you should probably change your question tag to javascript.

Comment: I tried what you said, but it will give me an error unless i only enter two digits

Comment: Here's scorkla's solution minus the pattern attribute: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvD93/) Recommended.

Comment: Frankenscarf's link works well. Alternatively, I edited my pattern so it should work. Not stupid, just need to do a lot more html and javascript tutorials. :)

Comment: Both the html and javascript sections in fiddle are the code you'd need, but you'd also need to import the [jquery library](http://jquery.com/) in the page(s) head

Comment: Can you post it as a reply on here what would work, you see my tutor didnt teach us Html, he gave us a starting code and said use the internet to develop it until the task is reached, and evidence it on powerpoint, so my stupidity in Html is my teachers fault haha

Comment: This will work, and so will the fiddle posted by Frankenscarf. The input I posted will replace what you have in your .html file. The keyup function will go in a javascript (.js) file. You then link the files by doing something like [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/91242/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-javascript-file-using-script-tag). I think that's about all the help I can give. :)

Comment: Ive worked it out now and will edit my code to the answer incase anyone else shall want to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, use strlen() for checking the string lenght and is_numeric() for checking that they are numbers.

Comment: I am using java for this.

Comment: Even then, the methodology would be very much the same... there has to be equivalent functions in Javascript... or not?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the input attribute maxlength="4" will restrict the number of characters entered to 4.
If your audience is exclusively html5 you can change the input type to "number", otherwise it's going to be a matter of validation and user alerts.

Comment: And how would i do validation and user alerts?

Comment: I dont think its Html 5, i have two parts to the code, the top section is java and the second section is Html, however the code that i put above is html, but my colleges suggested isNan which is java if i am right.

Comment: see my comment on scorkla's answer