# How to restrict user input character length of HTML5 input type="number"?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, user-input

How do I restrict user input to a given length in an HTML5 `input[type=number]` textbox?

the answers to

[How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

do not handle illegal inputs

```
<input class="quantity" type="number" min="0" max="99999" maxlength="5" />

$("quantity").keyup(function(){
    var $field = $(this);
    if ($field.val().length > Number($field.attr("maxlength"))) {
        var value = $field.val().slice(0, 5);
        $field.val(value);
    }
});
```

I know the maxlength attribute is not supported, but I use it to obtain the given length.

The above code works fine in firefox, but in chrome and safari it works only if I input five "VALID" characters. When I start typing any invalid characters, e.g. "a", "b" etc., I am able to type in more letters and the textbox color changes to red.

I found that when the input becomes invalid the `$field.val()` returns always empty string and the `$field.val().length` returns `0`.

I even tried converting the keyCode to character intended to input and store it in a "data-value" attribute to the input box to check against and overwrite the value of the input but it didn't seem to be reliable.

Is there any solution with which I can make the `input[type=number]` behave same as `input[type=text][maxlength=5]`?

Comment: Chrome uses built-in validators for HTML5 special input types. Changing the type to "text" in js is the solution for the uniform behaviour.

Comment: hmm.. it probably works in `Firefox` because it might be defaulting back to `type=text`.. it shows that `type=number` isn't even supported in Firefox  http://caniuse.com/input-number

Comment: @mplungjan I have read that already. I am not eligible to comment on the response yet. I didn't get the specific answer what I am asking for. In fact the code I used above is from that question. But all seem to point out the cause but I want a solution. Please help.

Comment: Right, I see now I should have read the question more thoroughly.

Comment: Here is one you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361193/why-is-input-type-number-maxlength-3-not-working-in-safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion after testing a few things

1. it handles more than one field with the quantity class
2. it handles illegal input where supported
3. initialises by storing all `defaultValue`s of the fields with the class
4. handles a weirdness with .index()
5. works in IE<10 too
6. tested in Safari 5.1 on Windows - it reacted to the is(":invalid") which however is invalid in IE8

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/jAYEt/)

```
var inputQuantity = [];
$(function() {
  $(".quantity").each(function(i) {
    inputQuantity[i]=this.defaultValue;
     $(this).data("idx",i); // save this field's index to access later
  });
  $(".quantity").on("keyup", function (e) {
    var $field = $(this),
        val=this.value,
        $thisIndex=parseInt($field.data("idx"),10); // retrieve the index
    // NOTE :invalid pseudo selector is not valid in IE8 so MUST be last
    if (this.validity && this.validity.badInput || isNaN(val) || $field.is(":invalid") ) { 
        this.value = inputQuantity[$thisIndex];
        return;
    } 
    if (val.length > Number($field.attr("maxlength"))) {
      val=val.slice(0, 5);
      $field.val(val);
    }
    inputQuantity[$thisIndex]=val;
  });      
});
```

Comment: Finally!! Thanks a lot @mplungjan. This does almost what I wanted. With a slight modification I get what I wanted. [Modified code](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfg6H/11/)

Comment: I can't put it all in comments so I put it on fiddle. Your feedback is appreciated. Thanks. Is there any way I can put it here or could you please get my changes in your answer?

Comment: I updated again to handle some unexpected issues I found when testing IE

Comment: Did you test this in safari? It seems invalid characters are accepted.

Comment: I managed to make it work everywhere `if ((this.validity && this.validity.badInput) || $field.is(":invalid") || isNaN(val))` including windows Safari except for IOS Safari.

In IOS Safari we simply can't replace the value of invalid textbox.

Comment: Great. I updated my code. the is(":invalid") must come last to work in IE

Comment: Yes I noticed that, but is it possible even that to be prevented in IOS Safari?

Comment: Not that I can see. So the issue is that you can type some of the number keyboard things in, but if you leave the field, it removes them so you are 99% there

Comment: there is ONE last thing to do. You can onfocus start monitoring using setInterval and onblur stop monitoring. That might work.

Comment: What do you suggest to monitor and how would it help?

Comment: Actually we cannot. So ignore my last comment

Answer (score 2):

I don't know my answer is useful for you? But i happy if i can help you.
 you should write a js method and then use it in your html page.

```
function limit(element) {
  var max_chars = 2;

  if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
    element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
  }
}


<input type="number" onkey ="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this);">
```

Comment: Thanks! But we can't check element.value.length because it will return 0 when invalid characters are typed. Thus the condition won't satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

---

Since there is no uniform support for HTML5 input types I suggest using this script template until all browsers will support them.

```
$(".quantity").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("type", "text")
    var min = $(this).attr("min");
    var max = $(this).attr("max");
    $(this).removeAttr("min").removeAttr("max");
    $(this).keyup(function(){
        var $field = $(this);
        if ($field.val().length > Number($field.attr("maxlength"))) {
            var value = $field.val().slice(0, 5);
            //   add js integer validation here using min and max
            $field.val(value);
        }
    });
});
```

Then we can simply leave HTML5 elements untouched

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do that either. I have used the input[type=number] purposely to bring up the numeric onscreen keyboard on typing in an IOS safari browser. Changing it back to type=text would bring up the default alpha-numeric onscreen keyboard. It is the main reason I need to limit the length via JS.

Comment: oh ok. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361193/why-is-input-type-number-maxlength-3-not-working-in-safari sounds good though

Answer (score 0):

to dynamically set max limit

```
function limit(element,max_chars) {

  if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
    element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
  }
}


<input type="number" onkey ="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this,2);">
```