# How to restrict max width in html5 number input

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, input

input field should allow to enter numbers only in range -9.99 .. 99.99

I tried page below in desktop and mobile Chrome but it allows to enter big numbers, for example 99999

How to fix this using html5 ? I can for use of Chrome only it this is required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Soiduaeg" name="Soiduaeg" value="" maxlength="5" type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([\.|,][0-9]+)?">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try max="5" instead of maxlength

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `min` and `max` values to input element, ant provide `step="any"` or `step="0.01"` attribute:

```
<input id="number" type="number" step="any" min="-9.99" max="99.99" />
```

For checking inputed values You need some javascript:

```
var $input = document.querySelector('#number');
$input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    var val = parseFloat($input.value),
    min = parseFloat($input.getAttribute('min')),
    max = parseFloat($input.getAttribute('max'));

    if (val > max) {
        $input.value = max;
    } else if (val < min) {
        $input.value = min;
    }
});
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/devxlt/btzx5mjt/1/)

Comment: This allows to enter bigger numbers from keyboard. Pressing tab to keeps invalid number. How to fix so that invalid number is not allowed ?

Comment: This saves invalid data to database without any message. Form is submitted using ajax. Form can saved using hotkey. In this case blur does not occur. How to fix this ? Maybe loop over html5 controls in ajax sbmit method, show message and cancel submit if value is not valid.

Comment: Using keyup like in answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104094/how-to-restrict-user-input-character-length-of-html5-input-type-number?lq=1 max fix this. Sould your code added to keyup method ?

Comment: @Andrus You should validate data in backend (PHP/APSX/NodeJS/Java/Go/Whatever) event listeners for validation are just for quick data evaluation (I don't even use them in production). Key Up method is good if You need it, I don't like it because I can't edit value if entered too big number or to small number (it sets value to smallest available). However server side validation is is better than trying to solve everything in frontend. In Froontend anybody can remove JS or rules that are bind in form, or submit for using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

for decimal numbers , bind this to oninput event

ex: 5.2 (nnnnn.dd)

```
//max number positions 5 before '.' or ','
var n = 5;
//max number of digit
var d = 2;
//max text length 8
var l = n + d + 1;

if (this.value.length > n && 
   (this.value.indexOf('.') == -1 && this.value.indexOf(',') == -1))
{ 
    this.value = this.value.slice(0,n); 
} 
else 
{ 
    if (this.value.length > l)  
        this.value = this.value.slice(0,l); 
};
if (
    (this.value.indexOf('.') != -1 && this.value.length - d >= this.value.indexOf('.')) ||
    (this.value.indexOf(',') != -1 && this.value.length - d >= this.value.indexOf(','))
)
{
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.value.length - (this.value.length - (this.value.indexOf('.') +d+1)));
}
```