# <input> only numbers from 0 to 99

Tags: html

What do I have to change if only numbers from 0 to 99 should be allowed?

```
<input type="text" style="text-align:center" NAME="name" pattern="[0-99]" size="1" maxlength="2">
```

Now only numbers from 0 to 9 can be entered.

Comment: of course it is in a <form>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use min and max and also set it as a type of number.

E.g

```
<input type="text" style="text-align:center" type="number" NAME="name" min="0" max="99" size="1" maxlength="2">
```

[Read more about it here.](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/whats-new-in-html5-forms-handling-numeric-inputs-using-the-number-and-range-input-types.html#fbid=Yu9oJzFUPyH)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" style="text-align:center" type="number" NAME="name" min="0" max="99" size="1" maxlength="2">
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression for matching numbers 0 to 99 is "[0-9]?[0-9]"

Comment: well 0 would then be 00... that's quite uncomfortable!

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qa5xS/)

With regex:

```
<form action="demo.php">
  <input type="text" name="xxxxx" pattern="^([0-9][0-9]?|)$">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```