# Validating Information Has Been Input

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering if anyone was able to help me with a JavaScript validation routine, Im trying to make it so that the Exam ID Number gets validated after information has been submit, So far all that is needed is name and subject and it will allow the examiner to proceed through without entering the exam ID number, Can anyone help me with this.

```
<script language="javascript"" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
            var result = true;
            var msg="";

if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your name \n";
            document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your Exam ID Number \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('Exam Number').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}


if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
            }


}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}
</style>

<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
  <table width="50%" border="0">
            <tr>
                            <td id="name">Name</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                            <td id="Exam Number">Exam ID Number</td>
                            <td><input type="Number" name="ID Number"maxlength="4" >        </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"     onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the problem with this? Do you want to validate the last field too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validateForm() {
            var result = true;
            var msg = "";
            if (document.getElementById("txtname").value == "") {
                msg += "You must enter your name \n";
                document.getElementById("name").focus();
                document.getElementById('name').style.color = "red";
                result = false;
            }

            if (document.getElementById("txtsubject").value == "") {
                msg += "You must enter the subject \n";
                document.getElementById("subject").focus();
                document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "red";
                result = false;
            }

            if (document.getElementById("ID_Number").value == "") {
                msg += "You must enter your Exam ID Number \n";
                document.getElementById("ID_Number").focus();
                document.getElementById('Exam Number').style.color = "red";
                result = false;
            }


            if (msg == "") {
                return result;
            }
            else {
                alert(msg)
                return result;
            }


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="ExamEntry">
    <h1>
        Exam Entry Form</h1>
    <table width="50%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="name">
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtname" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="subject">
                Subject
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtsubject" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="Exam Number">
                Exam ID Number
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="Number" id="ID_Number" maxlength="4">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please copy and paste my script into a thread and show roughly where it should be please :)

Comment: I have given in the whole script tag

Comment: It didnt work, I replaced the code with the code yougave me and it just proceeded to the next page without taking any information atall

Comment: I have modified few things .. here is the full html code

Comment: This helps so much. thank you, Just need to work out where some of the missing code goes now :P

Comment: never mind found it, Some of the code doesn't work, any idea on why the maxlength="4"> Doesnt work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element

Comment: Yeah i knowthe code, its just the fact it isnt working where it is placed, Sorry if this is an inconvenience, any suggestions?

Comment: may be u can add that as another question since i am signing off now .. good day