# HTML maxlength attribute not working on google chrome if input type of field is number

Tags: html, attr

```
<input type="number" maxlength="2" />
```

Its working in other browsers like Firefox,IE and not working in google chrome.Can any one suggest how to fix issue in chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add maxlength for HTML5 input type="number" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

Answer (score 0):

because it's a number, you can use max, not maxlength.

Comment: Not working with max.impacted other browsers also with this change

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow only two digit number then you can use following code

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="99" />
```

Comment: This piece of code I already tested not working..allowed more than two digits also in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Use the max attribute for inputs of type="number". 
It will specify the highest possible number that you may insert

```
   <input type="number" max="999" />
```

if you add both a max and a min value you can specify the range of allowed values:

```
    <input type="number" min="1" max="999" />
```

For user experience, you would prefer the user not to be able to enter more than a certain number, use Javascript/jQuery.

```
EG: <input type="number" max="99" min="9" id="myInput"/>

    $('#myinput').on('keydown', function () {
        if($(this).val().length>2)
              return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `max=""` and there is has to be a `form` element for it to work otherwise it won't work.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fjpNF/)

Comment: `max=xx` by itself won't solve the problem.  You could enter a higher precision float and still have it be considered valid while defeating the char count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="tel" maxlength="2" />
```