# I want to re-present to the user data user entered in a form

Tags: html

My php form validation is OK.  I want to keep user entered data in the form when it is represented to the user (i.e., if an error occurs).  I can do with for text entries using this code:

```
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id ="firstname" value = "<?php echo $firstname;?>"      >
```

And for radio buttons using this code:

```
    <input type="radio" name="entree" <?php if (isset($entree) && $entree =="chicken") echo "checked";?> value = "chicken">Chicken
```

But I can't get it to work for decimal inputs, using the following code.

```
     <input type="DECIMAL(4,2)" name = "meal_cost" id ="meal_cost"  value = "<?php echo    htmlspecialchars($meal_cost);?>">
```

I will appreciate any help from Stackoverflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add maxlength for HTML5 input type="number" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'Decimal(4,2)' input type in html. Just use `<input type="number"... />`

You can set a max and a min value on the input by using `max` and `min` attributes. Checkout the spec on input number types: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html

Also you can use the php `number_format` function to format the values when you are rendering the form and limit it to 2 decimals. That doesn't mean the user will submit only 2 decimals. You would need to add something to verify / correct values at they are posted to the server.

Putting it all together, you should change

```
<input type="DECIMAL(4,2)" name = "meal_cost" id ="meal_cost"  value = "<?php echo    htmlspecialchars($meal_cost);?>">
```

To

```
<input type="number" max="9999" min="0" step="any" name="meal_cost" id="meal_cost" value="<?php echo number_format($meal_cost,2);?>">
```