# HTML5 Date Input 6 digit year

Tags: html, date

I have a standard `<input />` control on my form, decorated with `type="date"`

When rendered, it displays the correct watermark of `yyyy-mm-dd`, and you can *select* a date correctly.
However, when you try *type in* a value, the **year** extends to 6 digits, instead of four. I have added screenshots to help demonstrate the issue I'm having.

Is anyone else getting this? I'm using Chrome ( Version 35.0.1916.153 m ) as my default browser.
I'd like a way to force a 4year input that doesn't involve extra JS.

[image: Date Control]

[image: Control Source]

Answer (score 31):

the max attribute is working, as far as i know...

the format of max is trickey, if you put the correct format everything will work fine....

see here for example:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min_date

Comment: Selected as the correct answer as it's a non-JS fix.

Comment: It's still allowing to type 6 digit year instead of 4

Comment: Note that when using `type="datetime-local"` you need a max formatted like `yyyy-mm-ddT00:00` for this to work.

Comment: This only affects the browser validator, unfortunately. Still 6 (or 5 on Firefox) digits can be typed.

Comment: As @Tristan said, it works in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox. Is there a universal solution?

Comment: This won't work in Safari though https://caniuse.com/input-datetime right now

Answer (score 26):

Use `max` attribute to fix this problem like:-

```
<input type="date" max="1979-12-31">
```

Comment: This won't work in Safari though https://caniuse.com/input-datetime right now

Answer (score 18):

A bit old, but for posterity...

Using the `max` attribute eliminates this problem.

```
<input type="date" max="2999-12-31">
```

Pen: https://codepen.io/iHearRobots/pen/OQVzLZ

Comment: I don't agree that this "eliminates" the problem. As of Chrome 70, for example, I can type a 6 digit year. IMO, it should stop me from typing past the number of digits in the max year. It might get "validated" as incorrect, but validations are still not standard.

Comment: This only seems to work if the users use the little toggle up and down buttons (in Chrome at least). It doesn't prevent typing data outside of the range though.

Comment: This won't work in Safari though https://caniuse.com/input-datetime right now

Comment: On firefox you can still input a longer year. Max only works for 4 digit years

Answer (score 9):

It will let you type a larger year. It wasn't designed with a cap, so to allow years beyond 9999. Not sure why.  (note, even with the `max` attribute, it doesn't appear to restrict it. [edit] .. it may not allow the user to actually submit after entering that larger number.)

You will need to use a JavaScript solution if you want to fully restrict it.

[See this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

Comment: Silly, as the mask shows a 4-digit year. So this is happening for everyone?

Comment: @SemiDemented - yes at least for webkit browsers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
const maxLengthCheck (event) ->{ 
    let date = event.target.value
    if(date){
        let dateArr date.split('-') 
        if(dateArr[0] && dateArr[0].length>4){ 
             dateArrl[0]=dateArr[0].substr(e, dateArr[0].length-1) 
             date = dateArr.join('-')
             console.log("updated date : ", date) 
             document.getElementById('date-input').value = date
        }
    }
}

//HTML changes
<input id="date-input" type="date" onInput={maxLengthCheck}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was the code below:

```
<input type="datetime-local" max="9999-12-31T23:59">
```

The max string format was key to do the trick.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue in Edge, it still allows typing six digits.

Answer (score 0):

The `max="2999-12-31"` is useful for validation.
But to prevent the entry of more than 4 digits on year, the only solution I can see is to use JS.

```
<input type="date" oninput="if(this.value.length > 10) this.value = this.value.replace(/\d{5,}/, match => match.substr(0, 4));"/>
```

Note that if you continue to press the key, the year will be reset - this is normal behavior (tested on FF).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, html5 provides fields `max` and `min`. You can use these fields based on requirements without involving JS.

I have updated your input and added snippets here, Try it in your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Date Published </title>
</head>
<body>
  <input
    class="form-control"
    data-val="true"
    data-val-date="The field DatePublished must be a date."
    data-val-required="The DatePublished field is required."
    id="DatePublished"
    name="DatePublished"
    required="true"
    type="date"
    value=""
    min="2000-01-01"
    max="2999-12-31"
  />
</body>
</html>
```