# Set input type number limit

Tags: html, input

I have to set limit of input number limit so that user can type only 3 numbers.
here my input tag:

```
           <input type="number" name="age" id="age" class="inPadd" maxlength="3">
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add maxlength for HTML5 input type="number" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

Comment: @Juhana User can type only 3 number in age.

Answer (score 0):

You should use attributes `min="0"` and `max="999"` instead of `maxlength`

```
 <input type="number" name="age" id="age" class="inPadd" min="0" max="999">
```