# I am using a text box which would allow only two digits(i.e.,1-99). It should restrict all other keys except 1-99 while entering into the textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a text box. It should restrict all other keys except 1-99 while entering into the textbox. i need code to restrict them.

Comment: On SO it's appreciated when you make an effort at solving your issue. What have you tried? Please show the current code you're using and what specifically it isn't doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this);">
```

**LIMIT With JS**

```
function limit(element)
{
var max_chars = 2;

   if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
       element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
   } 
}
```

Comment: i want to restrict the other keys like 123, 786,etc. the third digit should also be restricted.

Comment: yes, with this way you can validate with regular expression
var regular /^[0-9]{1,99}$/

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided for this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element) should help you figure it out. It's a combination of HTML and JavaScript. There are two main ideas:
1 - use input with type=number as Ghulam Ali suggested to restrict inputs to your range of values and augment that with some JS to restrict the length.
2 - use input with type=text to restrict the length and augment it with some JS to restrict inputs to your range of values.