# Allow only 2 numbers on input type number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set a range between 0 and 99 on a input type number? I am using HTML5 attributes ( `min="0" max="99"` ) but it's not working and as far as I know this kind of attribute is not supported by some browsers.

So I am using this script which blocks non-numerical characters but I want to limit the numbers to a max of 99 (only 2 digits). How can I do that?

Also I want to allow users to use the keyboard to type the numbers.

```
$(".js-number").numeric();
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/gnLz004r/)**

Comment: min="2" max="2" simple attribute of HTML5

Comment: @CodeLove, not working..

Comment: `$(".js-number").numeric();` any library?

Comment: its working man. I have update http://jsfiddle.net/gnLz004r/2/ 
put more than two number then enter or click anywhere, it will says Please select a value more than 2.....

Comment: @CodeLove, It is not saying so in chrome 46.0.2490.80. Op wants to limit the numbers

Comment: then use javascript for going to http://jsfiddle.net/ySt7S/86/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works if you remove the $(".js-number").numeric();
But you can edit the input.
maxlength attribute works on input type text, so I guess javascript validation is inevitable.

```
 <input type="number" class="js-number" min="0" max="99" value="0">   
 <script>
    $(".js-number").bind('keydown', function(e){
       var targetValue = $(this).val();
       if (e.which ===8 || e.which === 13 || e.which === 37 || e.which === 39 || e.which === 46) { return; }

       if (e.which > 47 &&  e.which < 58  && targetValue.length < 2) {
          var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
          var val = parseInt(c);
          var textVal = parseInt(targetValue || "0");
          var result = textVal + val;

          if (result < 0 || result > 99) {
             e.preventDefault();
          }

          if (targetValue === "0") {
            $(this).val(val);
            e.preventDefault();
          }
       }
       else {
           e.preventDefault();
       }
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: It's working. You can not edit it using keystrokes only by clicking the arrows of the input

Comment: But this is not ideal. I want to allow users to type the number using the keyboard.

Comment: You should have mentioned it. You'll need different javascript validation approach

Comment: I've just added that on the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input class="test-input" type="number" maxlength="12" />
<script>
$('.test-input').unbind('keyup change input paste').bind('keyup change input paste',function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    var valLength = val.length;
    var maxCount = $this.attr('maxlength');
    if(valLength>maxCount){
        $this.val($this.val().substring(0,maxCount));
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function format(input){
    if(input.value < 0) input.value=Math.abs(input.value);
    if(input.value.length > 2) input.value = input.value.slice(0, 2);
    $(input).blur(function() {
       // if(input.value.length == 1) input.value=0+input.value;
       // if(input.value.length == 0) input.value='01';
       //* if you want to allow insert only 2 digits *//
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="number" step="1" oninput="format(this)">
```

It works for me... hope for you as well :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set like this:

```
<input type="text" class="js-number" maxlength="2">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element

Comment: @RayonDabre Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: @brunodd, `maxlength` will work but it will accept characters too if type is not a number

Comment: this is a wrong answer title says `Allow only 2 numbers` who is upvoting this  answer

Comment: @RayonDabre it seems that if I remove type="number" it works: http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/gnLz004r/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `maxlength="2"` in `input` of **html** and `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '')` in **Javascript** function

- `maxlength="2"` : It allows only two entries in the input by text (lets take it number) so the maximum two digit number is 99 and minimum two digit number is -9 (`-` is also considered as a entry) but if `-` sign is removed than minimum number is 00 , **which solves the range of 00-99**

Now the `input` is `type=text` so any alphabet can be entered along with symbols (`-` `@` `$`...) to solve that **JavaScript** [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

- `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '')` : It take the value from the input on each entry of a digit and check if it is a number or not . If it is a number then the entry will be leaved as it is but if entry is not a number than it is replace by `''` means removed from the input . So **only number entry is solved without a `-` sign too**

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("orderUnits")[0].addEventListener("input", amountofUnits);

function amountofUnits() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="orderUnits" maxlength="2">
```