# "maxlength" is not working with input type="number" in html textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Maxlength is not working with type="number"

Comment: Take a look at this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `maxlength` attribute for `number` input.

There are `max` and `min` attributes instead.

This HTML will provide a number with the maximum length of 3:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="999"/>
```

Note that it is still possible to enter bigger numbers manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="number" max="100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this instead

```
<input type="number" name="MyInteger" min="1" max="99">
```