# How can I restrict input to 4-digit number

Tags: html

I want to retrieve a 4-digit employee id from the user. How can I restrict the input field to 4-digit?

```
<tr>
<td>4 digit Employee ID:</td>
<td><input type = "number" name = "employee_id" size = "20"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<tr>
<td>4 digit Employee ID:</td>
<td><input type = "text" name = "employee_id"  pattern="[0-9]{4}" title="4 digit number: e.g. 1234" required></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: pattern and required attributes comes with HTML5

Answer (score 2):

You can use min and max

```
<input type="number" name="employee_id" min="1" max="9999">
```

Referance: [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element?rq=1)

Comment: I tried that, but that would allow them to enter non-four digit numbers unfortunately. However, the person below suggested to use the maxlength attribute, I think that will work! Thanks very much for your input though!

Answer (score 1):

Use maxlength attribute :

```
<input type = "number" name = "employee_id" size = "20" maxlength= "4">
```

Comment: this one doesn't need html5, so it is one useful attribute

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use a jquery plugin, like the one at http://jqueryvalidation.org/.

Since you want to restrict to only 4 digits it'd be something like this:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
  field: {
     required: true,
     digits: true,
     maxlength: 4
  }
}
```

});