# Input type number maxlength 5

Tags: javascript

I want to limit the input type number to maximum 5 numbers, I am using below code, which is working well, only issue is that for backspace I have to use event.keycode which I dont want to use. Is there any alternative apart from usking keycode of backspace.

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('keypress',showData,false)
function showData(event)
{
   if(event.target.value.length<=5)
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      event.preventDefault();
   }

}
```

Comment: Not valid for input type "number"

Comment: Correct. Should delete the comment :P

Comment: Why not use `keyup` instead of `keypress`? Then you don't need to worry about backspace

Comment: This answer describes how to limit input type text to only allow numeric characters. You can extend this and use maxlength=5 afterwards. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Comment: @mikeyq6 : tried keyup is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it so if the user tries to type more than 5 numbers it only keeps the 5 numbers:

```
input.oninput = function() {
    if (this.value.length > 5) {
        this.value = this.value.slice(0,5); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: @user3045179 You could simplify it inside the oninput function to: `this.value = (this.value.length > 5) ? this.value.slice(0,5) : this.value;`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use:

```
<input type="number" max="99999">
```

This will still not stop a user from manually entering a value larger than 99999, but the input element will be invalid.

Comment: Yes I checked that but requirement is that it should be visible that input is not more than 5 digit

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" max="99999" />
```

[How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

Comment: I have searched stackoverflow, but I found the min and max solution only and unfortunately, this is not what i require.

Comment: Remove the min attribute. Or user jquery validator plugin

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
<input required type="text" name="inputname" pattern="[0-9]{5,}">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```