# using html attributes in JSX

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use the maxLength attribute in JSX, but the examples I've found are not working.

```
<div>
    <input type="Number" maxLength={5}/>
</div>
```

This is what I have currently, and I've tried:

```
maxLength="5"

maxLength={"5"}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you're using integers, try setting `max="99999"`. [MDN on `<input />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is not with react or JSX at all. The problem is that input type "number" does not support maxlength property. It support property "max". For example:

```
<input type="Number" max="99"/>
```

Will allow numbers up to 99.

Also JSX does support maxLength property and you can write it like:

```
maxLength="5"
maxLength={"5"}
maxLength={5}
```

It will be the same thing

Comment: I see, I chose to use text because I wanted to restrict typing after 9chars. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use the type of "Number" ? maxLength will work with "text", however you would want to use max with number to define the max limit of the range of acceptable numbers. however, it won't prevent a user from entering more numbers then you specified, as answered here,

[How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

Comment: Thank you, this was also useful.