# How to set maximum length in input type=number?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text field.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="999">
```

But i am able to type as many numbers inside the text box.

As I set max=999, I don't want that to happen.
Anyone knows the solution for this?
I have tried `ng-maxlength` and `maxlength` but doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly you need? Your question is not clear.

Comment: you create a text feild and give max=999, and still you will be able to type 111111111 (even if not  a valid entry) i want to block that, i dont want to block entering 4 digit number in the text feild

Comment: use regex pattern for that like this. ^(\d){1,10}$

Comment: Can you show us some verifiable example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/avyzdedc/

Comment: in the fiddle i have limit 999, still you will be able to type as many numbers as you want

Comment: i found that maxlength property only work in  type="text" so i need a solution

Comment: Try This Tag <input type="text" maxlength="3"> or you have to use the script function on change to restrict the user to enter Value.

Comment: <input type="text"  maxlength="3" size="3">

Comment: `min` and `max` are used for validation purpose, they don't prevent you from writing inside the input not valid numbers.

Comment: Why do you care? As long as there's only 3 characters max when the data is submitted. How the user gets to 3 characters is up to them.

Comment: I think you get your ans from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`max` attribue specifies the maximum possible value that we can specify.

for more details [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

I think the following will be helpful to you,

```
//maxlength="10"
<input type="number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==10) return false;" />
```

Comment: when it reaches 10 charectors, i am not able to remove the number(backspace not working)

Comment: Changed onKeyDown to onKeyPress... check once again

Comment: [Firefox Quantum]The same is happening, neither backspace or another key works. It can only be changed with the number's arrows up or down.                 [Chrome] Works fine!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress

Comment: If you're using React, you may have to use `onKeyPress={(e) => { if (e.target.value.length >= 12) e.preventDefault() }}`

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me is to use onkeypress with the max attribute.
For e.g. for max length of 999

```html
<input type="number" max="999" onkeypress="if (this.value.length > 2) return false;"/>
```

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Comment: It works, but if you input operators like plus and minus, it destroys the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  var oldNumber = 0;
  $scope.numberChanged = function(number){
    if(number<=999){
      oldNumber = number;
    }
    return oldNumber;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div  ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="number" min="0" max="999" ng-model="jimNum" ng-change="jimNum = numberChanged(jimNum);">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="999" 
   onKeyUp="if(this.value>999){this.value='999';}else if(this.value<0){this.value='0';}"
id="yourid">
```

Comment: Note that if the user adjusts the value using the field controls, they likely will not dispatch any keyboard event, so the *onkeyup* listener won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

There is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oax8z0hy/), using JQuery.

Your input

```
<input type="number" id="num">
```

The script :

```
$("#num").keypress( function(e) {
    var current_val = $(this).val();
    var typing_char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
if (parseFloat(current_val + "" +typing_char) > 900) {
    return false;
}

})
```

Comment: That restricts the maximum value to 900, and allows any size negative number. Far better would be something like `var v = this.value; if (v > 999) this.value = v.substr(0,2)` with additional logic for negative numbers (whatever they might be).

Comment: yeah, my bad, forgot about the min val, but he can fix it easily with all answer now.

Answer (score 0):

if you are limit the single field

```
  <TextField type="number"
    className="text-field-amount"
    onInput={(e)=>{ 
        e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,2)
    }}
    min={0}
```

Comment: It limits the numbers up to 2 digits

Answer (score 0):

if you are mapping more then one number Text field through map then do like this

```
     <TextField
                      key={key}
                      label={row.q_desc}
                      type="number"
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      onInput={this.onInput}

                    />

    onInput= event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    debugger;
    var textField_name = this.state.input_Name;
    if (textField_name == "Zip") {
      event.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(event.target.value))
        .toString()
        .slice(0, 4);
    }

    if (textField_name == "Social Security") {
      event.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(event.target.value))
        .toString()
        .slice(0, 9);
    }
    if (textField_name == "Phone") {
      event.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(event.target.value))
        .toString()
        .slice(0, 10);
    }
  };



 onChange(e) {
          debugger;

         this.setState({
            input_Name: e.target.name
         });
  }
```