# How to limit the number of digits in number input?

Tags: html, input

I am creating a form that will allow a user to enter a birthday with month, day and year. For year, I am trying to write the html code such that it will only allow positive number and also limit it to 4 digits. Here is the code in question:

```html
<input type="number" name="year" maxlength="4"  max="9999" min="0" step="1" placeholder="YYYY" p="[0-9]{4}" style="color:#888;" required/>
```

I've scoured the web for a solution to what I am trying to do but every time I try it, it will allow me to enter a number that is greater than 4 digits... basically I am trying to limit the user to enter a valid birth year:

Any advice?? thanks in advance!!

[Birth year greater than 4 digits input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLYT6.png)

Comment: Oh, and for this project I have been advised that I shouldnt use type as "text", for that could cause issues with my program down the road.

Comment: `p="[0-9]{4}"` should be `pattern="[0-9]{4}"` (or atleast I've never encounter `p` attribute) That also requires the browser is HTML5 compatible.. You had PHP tag, is there PHP? You also could use JS.

Comment: nope, unfortunately that doesn't change a thing :(

Comment: maxlength doesn't work with numbers (at least in chrome). without type="number" it works as expected. Doesn't really help, I know.

Comment: You've asked six questions and never accepted an answer. People are going to get tired of helping you if you keep that behaviour up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set maximum length in input type=number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538357/how-to-set-maximum-length-in-input-type-number)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Answer (score 2):

thank you kennytm, your link has answered by question. I just needed to add this

```
onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==10) return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Two changes are required:

1. Change input `type=number` to `type=text`. This will start accepting text input without constraints.
2. BUT your regular expression pattern will bound text input to numbers only.
3. Also edit `p=[0-9]{4}` to `pattern="[0-9]{4}"`.

```html
<input type="text" name="year" maxlength="4"  min="0" max="9999" step="1" placeholder="YYYY" pattern="[0-9]{4}" style="color:#888;" required/>
```