# Max in Numeric TextBox

Tags: html

I know we can restrict the user to enter numbers less than specific max number by below code.

```
    <input id="txt" max="9999" type="number">
```

If user enters anything more than 9999 a tooltip will appear above textbox asking user to enter number less than 9999. Is there way to restrict user to enter only max 4 numbers in textbox. System will not allow numbers enter any thing in text box after 4 digits are entered.

This is working with normal texbox using below code but for numeric textbox, system allows to enter n digits.

```
   <input id="txt" maxlength="4" type="text">
```

P.S. I have already done validation using Jquery, if user enters more than 4 digits, system will notify users. My requirement is user should not be allowed to enter 5th digit at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add maxlength for HTML5 input type="number" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery

```
$("#txt").blur(function() {  

    if ($('#txt').length > 4) {
        $('#txt').before('your notice');
    }
```

});

Comment: I am doing this, Problem is my requirement is user should not be allowed to enter for than 4 digits in textbox.. at present if user enters more than 4 digits application will display error. I am doing that using jquery validation.

Comment: replace "blur" with "keyup"