# How to set maximum number of characters in number type textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one textbox which is of number type. I want it to accept maximum of 16 digits, not more than that. For that I have tried with "maxlength" attribue and "max" attribute both. But its not working. Can anyone provide me solution?

```
<input type="number" id="dummy" max="16" />
```

Edit: I need to enter only whole number since it is used for account number of bank.

Comment: Please define "its not working".

Comment: And be more specific about what you want to allow. Only whole numbers? Up to 16 digits left of the decimal? Right of it? A total of 16 regardless of where the decimal is? Or 15 plus the decimal? (E.g., are you trying to *very roughly* avoid precision issues with IEEE-754 double-precision floating point values?)

Comment: Have look at this reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element

Comment: If you only care about whole numbers, see the question Sasikumar linked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few of these "how do I further control `type="number"` fields" questions here on SO. It boils down to:

1. You make it a `type="number"` and accept that you can't further mask the input vs. what the browser does to implement a numeric input, or
2. You make it `type="text"` and use [`pattern`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) and/or [`maxlength`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-maxlength) to enforce the specific pattern you want, and accept that the browser won't add a specific UI for numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Input type number doesn't support "maxlength" attribute. You can specify "max" attribute (HTML5), which is the highest number user can input. Something like this: `<input type="number" max="999999999999" id="dummy" step="1" min="0">`.
Edit: Also specify `step` attribute to 1.

Comment: `0.1234567890123456789` is `< 9999999999999999`.

Comment: Re "edit": Okay, now you're assuming that the OP only wants positive whole numbers (or 0), which he/she never says in the question.