# HTML - Not working maxlength in chrome and safari

Tags: html

I am using type as number for input field. On clicking on top & down arrows of input field, we are able to select upto max length 99. But If I enter I can able to enter many values(numbers). It's issue in chrome? I provided restriction for maxlength as 2. But its not working. How to restrict?

```
        <input type="number" min="1" max="99" maxlength="2">
```

Comment: Has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-to-add-maxlength-for-html5-input-type-number-element 
as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
<input type="number" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" />
```

Comment: The OP stated, in their question, that that did not work.

Comment: This will restrict to increase upto number 2 only @xestes

Comment: This could also be improved with `onKeyDown="return (this.value.length<=2);"`