# MaxLength on number not working

Tags: html, angular

> i using angular 4.3.3

maxlength 11 max span  message is not showing

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="orderId"   [(ngModel)]="orderIdModel"  name="orderId" #orderId="ngModel" required  maxLength="11"  />
<div *ngIf="orderId.errors">
                    <span *ngIf="orderId.errors.required"class="not-valid">required</span>
                    <span *ngIf="orderId.errors.maxlength"class="not-valid"> 11 max</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Not working how, exactly...? Please see [ask], check out the [tour] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: maxlength message is not showing

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use 'ngModelChange' to force the validation and correct a little bit the markup:

```
<input class="form-control" id="orderId" required maxlength="11" 
        type="number" name="orderId" [ngModel]="orderIdModel" 
        (ngModelChange)="orderIdModel = $event + ''" #orderId="ngModel" /> 
<span *ngIf="orderId.errors?.required">
      required
</span>
<span *ngIf="orderId.errors?.maxlength">
    11 max
</span>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sycvny)**

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think you need to use `max` instead</strike>

```ts
max="99999999999"
```

See also [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

`min` and `max` are only available for model-driven forms by default.

I created a directive that makes `max` available to template-driven forms, by copying and adapting the source of the `maxLength` validator from https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fcadbf4bf6d00ea5b250a8069e05b3e4bd000a29/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/G9InBjFn4kQbxQeZYvYi?p=preview)

```ts
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, Directive, forwardRef, Input} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FormsModule, Validators, NG_VALIDATORS} from '@angular/forms'
```

```ts
export const MAX_VALIDATOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => MaxValidator),
  multi: true
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[max][formControlName],[max][formControl],[max][ngModel]',
  providers: [MAX_VALIDATOR],
  host: {'[attr.max]': 'max ? max : null'}
})
export class MaxValidator implements Validator,
    OnChanges {
  private _validator: ValidatorFn;
  private _onChange: () => void;

  @Input() max: string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if ('max' in changes) {
      this._createValidator();
      if (this._onChange) this._onChange();
    }
  }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null {
    return this.max != null ? this._validator(c) : null;
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void { this._onChange = fn; }

  private _createValidator(): void {
    this._validator = Validators.max(parseInt(this.max, 10));
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form #orderId="ngForm" ngForm>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="orderId"
          [(ngModel)]="orderIdModel"  name="orderId" #orderId="ngModel" required min="10" max="999"  />
          <div>errors: {{orderId.errors | json}} </div>
      <div *ngIf="orderId.errors">
        <span *ngIf="orderId.errors.required"class="not-valid">required</span>
        <span *ngIf="orderId.errors.max"class="not-valid"> 11 max</span>
      </div> 
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MaxValidator ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Did you change `orderId.errors.maxlength` to `orderId.errors.max`? Do you get any error message?

Comment: "not working" is pretty close to "no information at all".

Comment: change to max ="99999999999"  and orderId.errors.max, nit working, message not showing and orderId.valid = true