# Can't apply limit on the input field of type=number

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Below is my input field of `type="number"`. I have applied the min and the max attributes to restrict the user to enter the value of the field. The problem is this given validation is still allowing the user beyond the limit while he types the numerical value. Please tell me how can I stop him/her entering the value above the limit.

```
 <input name="capacity" [(ngModel)]="nService.capacity" type="number" 
class="input-minimal" min="1" max="9999" placeholder="Capacity" required>
```

Comment: It usually wont stop. But angular validation will throw error. You can prevent user from proceeding further with validation or still if you want to limit the number of characters you need a custom directive

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: This problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936352/html-number-input-min-and-max-not-working-properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting attributes `max` and `min` on an input with `type = "number"` will prevent the user from incrementing/decrementing the value with the spinner. But it will not prevent the keyboard input. To do so, you would have to write a custom validator.

In my example I binded to the `keyup` event with an optional error validation block, just in case you prefer to leave the user to correct herself.

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4fCj7OTamUC82cUfTRo2)**

**HTML:**

```
 <input autofocus id="myModel" (keyup)="preventInput($event)" 
       name="myModel" 
        #myModel="ngModel"  style="width:60px"  
        [(ngModel)]="capacity" type="number" 
       class="input-minimal" min="1" max="99" 
       placeholder="Capacity" required>
```

**Typescript:**

```
 preventInput(event){
    let value=this.capacity;
    if (value >= 100){
      event.preventDefault()
      this.capacity = parseInt(value.toString().substring(0,2));
    }
  }
```

P.S. for the validation part I used the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46024784/5468463)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the validity before sending it.

Here is how, with [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) :

**HTML**

```
<form novalidate (onSubmit)="submitForm()" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="number" formControlName="myNumber">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';


myForm: FormGroup;
constructor(prviate fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
        myNumber: [0, [Validators.max(9999), Validators.min(1)]]
    });
}

submitForm() {
    let value = this.myForm.value;
    if (this.myForm.valid) {
        // Here, do your stuff when the form is valid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code for custom directive which I restricted as attribute:

AngularJs Custom Directive for max length:

```
app.directive('inputMaxlength', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var maxlength = Number(attrs.inputMaxlength);
      function fromUser(text) {
          if (text.length > maxlength) {
            var transformedInput = text.substring(0, maxlength);
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
            return transformedInput;
          } 
          return text;
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  }; 
})
```

Use this custom directive in HTML like

```
<input type="text" input-maxlength=20 ......>
```

And for angular form validation lots of samples are there.

Comment: I'm using angular 2's NgForms

Comment: Sry my bad. We can use keyup event to restrict characters in angular 2 @YashwardhanPauranik