# Input min and max should be equal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to achieve user can only enter 10 numbers in input, also if the user put let's say 5 numbers that are also not allowed, so min and max should be 10.

```html
<input type="number" min="10" max="10" >
```

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Comment: `minlength` and `maxlength` are not valid attributes on a number input. Did you mean `min` and `max`? You seem to want to restrict the length of the number, so maybe the number input type is not what you need? Try using the text input type instead?

Comment: If the min and max values are 10, you could enter only 10 to the input. Can you please describe the conditions a bit more accurately?

Comment: I think where OP says '10 numbers', they mean '10 digits'.

Comment: @Teemu,  yes, can try to enter 50 number in my input, and you will see that input is not limited to 10 numbers?

Comment: @Mihalma the number input does not have the ability to restrict the length of a number. Why are you wanting to do this? Perhaps if we know the reason we can suggest a better approach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Answer (score 0):

`minlength` and `maxlength` attributes don't exist. Instead, use `min` and `max`.
I understand you want a 10 digits input only, so you should be doing:

```html
<input type="number" min="1000000000" max="9999999999">
```