# jQuery bvalidator not showing validation value in validation the message

Tags: jquery

I have a form with this input

```
...
<input type="number" name="age" data-bvalidator="max[120]">
...
<script src="{{ URL::to('theme/validate/jquery.bvalidator.min.js') }}"></script>
/* jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.18.0 */
```

when I enter 200, it shows

```
"Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."
```

It doesn't show the validation value in the curly brackets. How do I fix it?

Comment: Potentially: http://bmauser.github.io/bvalidator

Comment: Can you create a snippet with all the relevant CDN links and config?   Started but after error after error, it's taking too long:  https://jsfiddle.net/h0btjav3/

Comment: @freedomn-m I didn't use SDN. And I couldn't get the snippet work.

Comment: I think I just use jQuery validation instead.

Comment: You might find this of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8355050/2181514

Comment: You're right. We html5 has its own validation so I guess I don't need any jQuery validation. Btw, bvalidation according to this page works fine. https://www.cloudweblabs.com/validations-using-jquery-databvalidator/  It shows the validation value instead of {0}.