# input type number - max value

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an input

```
<input type="number" max="100">
```

However, if the user write manually for example 200, the input accept it. Is it something normal ?

I can validate the entry with javascript but if there is a build in in the html input it would be great :)

Thanks

Comment: In fact, HTML provides validation when submitting via POST method. However, I don't understand the question, you should learn more about how to make a proper question in Stackoverflow before posting.

Comment: `<input type="number" max="100" required >`

Comment: A popular recommendation is to actually not use `type="number"`, unless for the most basic circumstances, as its native features are quite shallow and not reliable across browsers. In a mature custom UI system, a fully-featured number field, with all the behaviours and safety you'd expect, is likely going to be a regular `type="text"` field, wrapped in a custom component where everything is manually handled: inputs, outputs, ui/ux, validations, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution directly with HTML; the `max` and `min` attributes only work when clicking the up arrow and down arrow keys. Check out the post in the references section for more information. The image below shows that the input does not change when the up arrow button is clicked, since the `max` attribute is 100:

[image]

In the solution below, when the `input` event of the `<input>` element is triggered, the data input is checked by checking the `max` attribute with the `isValid()` method. You can change the `disabled` property of the submit button according to the result returned by the `isValid()` method.

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input');

function isValid(value){
  if(parseInt(value) <= inputElement.getAttribute('max'))
    return true;
  return false;
}

inputElement.addEventListener('input', function () {
    if(isValid(this.value))
      console.log("true");
    else
      console.log("false");
});
```

```html
<input type="number" max="100">
```

---

###### References

- [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Comment: This answer is wrong. Did you test it out? Amazed it is selected answer when it says 2 is not valid....

Comment: The `isValid()` method returns `false` if the parameter is greater than 100. Where is wrong?

Comment: Try it! Enter 2

Comment: I didn't even notice. Thank you for your alert. I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually no "native" HTML way outside a form post to avoid the faulty manual entry. You could do something like this (here jquery code):

```
$('input[type="number"]').on('change input keyup paste', function () {
  if (this.max) this.value = Math.min(parseInt(this.max), parseInt(this.value) || 0);
});
```

This code applies to all inputs of type number in case of keyboard input, pasting, changing a validation method that checks, whether a max value exists and if so `Math.min()` returns the lowest-valued number passed into it. If the value is not a number 0 is returned.

See a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hennson/q4eLubkj/) at JSFiddle

In Vanilla JavaScript the handler would look like this:

```
var numElement = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]')
numElement.addEventListener('change', validateMax);
numElement.addEventListener('input', validateMax);
numElement.addEventListener('keyup', validateMax);
numElement.addEventListener('paste', validateMax);

function validateMax() {
   if (this.max) this.value = Math.min(parseInt(this.max), parseInt(this.value) || 0);
}
```

See a [demo of the vanilla version](https://jsfiddle.net/hennson/y3gapjd1/) at JSFiddle

This handler should do the trick.

Comment: It is advisable to put this in all pages that have the Number Input - This is quite Helpful

Answer (score -1):

If you are using form, you can just mark it as required and the form does the validation for you.

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="myNumber" name="myNumber" type="number" max="100" required >
  <button>Send It</button>
</form>
```

Now if you want to know if it is valid in JavaScript directly there is built in methods for that

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.getElementById("myNumber").value);
});


document.getElementById("check").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("form: ", document.getElementById("myForm").checkValidity());
  console.log("input: ", document.getElementById("myNumber").validity.valid);
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="myNumber" name="myNumber" type="number" max="100" required>
  <button>Send It</button>
</form>

<button type="button" id="check">Check It</button>
```