# How can I detect if backspace is pressed on the site?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently making a simple online text editor site. And I cannot detect backspace being pressed.
Here is the code:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssfile/style.css">
    <title> Code Editor </title>
    <script src="jsfile/main.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navdiv"></div>
    <div id="board" class="board">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

js:
This is my main code:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    console.log(event.key)
    if (event.key == "Enter") {
        document.getElementById("board").innerText += '\n'
    } else {
        document.getElementById("board").innerText += event.key
    }
});
```

This is my code and I tried

```
if(event.key == "Backspace")
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: when you press backspace what gets logged by your `console.log` line?

Comment: Is it useful?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353550/how-to-capture-a-backspace-on-the-onkeydown-event

Comment: @Jamiec no i tried that it didnt work. That made me confused

Comment: @AntonyNg Hi i also tried those methods but none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.

You are using `keypress` when you should be using `keyup` (or `keydown` if you want to know before the key press is complete).

KeyPress event is invoked only for character (printable) keys, KeyUp and KeyDown events is raised for all including non-printable such as Control, Shift, Alt, BackSpace, etc.

Try this:

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  console.log(event.key);
  if (event.key === "Backspace") {
    document.getElementById("board").innerText += '\n'
  } else {
    document.getElementById("board").innerText += event.key
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes i figured it out now, thanks for your help

Comment: Any time! Don't forget to accept if this answer helped!

Comment: Accepted this answer

Answer (score 2):

`keypress` event [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) and there's a change your browser doesn't support it. Use `keydown` instead.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    console.log(event.key)
    if (event.key == "Backspace") {
        document.getElementById("board").innerText += '\n'
    } else {
        document.getElementById("board").innerText += event.key
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes i did and upvoted the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `keypress` event is deprecated and triggers only when a key press produces a character value. Thus, it is not triggered with the backspace in your case.

You should use the `keydown` event.

Answer (score 0):

## 2021 Update: Use `keyup` & `event.key`

❌ Bad

- `keydown` lets you know when the key is pressed down, but this fires before any action takes place.
- `event.keyCode` is both difficult to interpret (numbers representing letters and all), and [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

✅ Good

- `keyup` fires after the backspace event has happened (i.e. a character was deleted), just like `keypress`
- `event.key` is both [universally supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#browser_compatibility) and [not deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

```html
<form>
  <label>Foo:
    <input name="foobar" placeholder="ex: foobar" />
  </label>
</form>
```

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="foobar"]').addEventListener('keyup', function (ev) {
  console.log(ev.key);
  if ("Backspace" == ev.key) {
    console.log("It's a backspace!!");
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `event.keyCode == 8`.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log(event.keyCode);
  if (event.keyCode == 8) {
    document.getElementById("board").innerText += '\n'
  } else {
    document.getElementById("board").innerText += event.key
  }
});
```

**KeyCode Docs:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#constants_for_keycode_value

Comment: 32 is the keyCode for Space bar. 8 is for backspace..

Comment: I figured it out i had to use keydown not keypress but still thanks for the help